# Multiple steps to process data, what's good pattern for JS/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Imagine we have few steps to process data. First we download it, then we do smth else and so on many times. Code in C# it would look like several lines - one for each step.

As I understand now, in JS/Angular it would look like this:

```js
function prepateAndGo() {

    loadData()
        .$promise.then((loadedData) => {

            prepareData(loadedData).$promise().then((preparedData) => {
           
                preprocessData(preparedData).$promise().then((preprocessedData) => {

                    andDoSmthElse(preprocessedData).$promise().then((andDoSmthElseData) => {

                        makeupData(andDoSmthElseData).$promise().then((makeupedData) => {

                            Console.log('finally, everything is loaded and processed, lets go');

                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
}
```

Isn't there more beautiful pattern? What's common solution against spaghetti?

Comment: It is [promise hell](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513#.tq0qxg56n), a sibling of callback hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create utility functions that return a promise. For example:

```
function prepareData(data){
    // do something with data and return a promise
    return $q.when(data);        
}
```

Then you can chain the promises nicely. For example:

```
loadData()
    .then(prepareData)
    .then(preprocessData)
    .then(andDoSmthElse)
    .then(makeupData)
    .then(function(madeData){
        Console.log('finally, everything is loaded and processed, lets go');
    });
```

*Note: Code is off the top of my head, but should get you started*

Comment: Right! Some methods arn't promises, so returning a promise "fromResult" is good move.

Answer (score 0):

Since each of your callbacks themselves return promises, you can chain the `.then()` calls like so:

```
function prepateAndGo() {

    loadData().$promise()
        .then(loadedData => prepareData(loadedData).$promise())
        .then(preparedData => preprocessData(preparedData).$promise())
        .then(preprocessedData => andDoSmthElse(preprocessedData).$promise())
        .then(andDoSmthElseData => makeupData(andDoSmthElseData).$promise())
        .then(makeupedData => {
            Console.log('finally, everything is loaded and processed, lets go');
         });

}
```

Additionally, [as Matt Way mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39638461/5436257), if you change your API to directly return promises, you can get rid of the arrow functions altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [promise chaining](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)?

```
action1()
    .$promise.then((result2) => action2(result2))
    .$promise.then((result3) => action3(result3))
    .$promise.then((result4) => action4(result4))
    .$promise.then((result5) => action5(result5))
    .$promise.then((finalResult) => console.log('Finally got it.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to make these chains more readable is simply to move some of the logic to separate functions. So:

```
function prepareAndGo() {
  loadData()
    .then(processData)
    .then(doSomethingElse)
    .then(whatever)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

function processData(data) {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(stuff)
}

function doSomethingElse(data) {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(stuff)
}

function whatever(data) {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(stuff)
}
```

A slightly more cutting edge approach is to use the `async/await` pattern, which you can read about more [here](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await). It's currently not really possible to use async/await without a transpiler, as support is lacking (but that will change soon!).

However, you can take advantage of this pattern today via [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), which were a new feature introduced in the javascript ES2015 specification. The promise library Bluebird offers a method called `coroutine` which wraps generator functions and makes them act like `async` functions. Here's an example:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")

let loadData = Promise.coroutine(function* (data) {

  let preparedData       = yield prepareData(data)
  let preprocessedData   = yield preprocessData(preparedData)
  let andDoSmthElseData  = yield andDoSmthElse(preprocessedData)
  let madeUpData         = yield makeupData(andDoSmthElseData)

  console.log('Everything is loaded and processed!')

  return madeUpData
})
```